# Using Pytube to download playlist from YouTube

Tags: python, pytube

I am looking to download a YouTube playlist using the [PyTube](https://github.com/nficano/pytube) library. Currently, I am able to download a single video at a time. I cannot download more than one video at once.

Currently, my implimentation is

```
import pytube

link = input('Please enter a url link\n')
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
stream = yt.streams.first()
finished = stream.download()
print('Download is complete')
```

This results in the following output

```
>> Download is complete
```

And the YouTube file is downloaded. When I try this with a playlist link ([An example](https://youtube.com/watch?v=QBK3QpQVnaw&start_radio=1&list=RDQMDhuypGgOBHA)) only the first video is downloaded. There is no error outputted.

I would like to be able to download an entire playlist without re-prompting the user.

Comment: "it shows error" is not a problem description. Please include the _full_ traceback in your post.

Comment: I've just ran your code, it works fine.

Comment: But it only downloads single video at a time but i want to download a whole playlist at a time @Glazbee

Comment: I've posted an answer for you.

Comment: pytube is no longer maintained, consider using pytube3 instead

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can import `Playlist` to achieve this. There is no reference to Playlist in the redoc, though there is a section in the [GitHub repo found here](https://github.com/nficano/pytube). The source of the script is in the  repo [here](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/master/pytube/contrib/playlist.py).

```
from pytube import Playlist

playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58PpYacL-VQ&list=UUd6MoB9NC6uYN2grvUNT-Zg')
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
playlist.download_all()
```

NOTE: I've found the supporting method `Playlist.video_urls` does not work. The videos are still downloaded however, [as evidenced here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV5MU.png)

Comment: The `playlist.video_urls` list is populated by the `populate_video_urls()` method, which is called by `playlist.download_all()`. Calling `populate_video_urls()` does seem to fill the list as expected.

Comment: playlist.download_all() is now deprecated and does not work.

Comment: Yes this is deprecated, i added a new solution for this.

Answer (score 20):

The solutions above no longer work. Here's a code which downloads the sound stream of the videos referenced in a Youtube playlist. Pytube3 is used, not pytube. Note that the playlist must be public for the download to succeed. Also, if you want to download the full video instead of the sound track only, you have to modify the value of the Youtube tag constant. The empty Playlist.videos list fix was taken from this Stackoverflow post:[PyTube3 Playlist returns empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661930/pytube3-playlist-returns-empty-list)

```
import re
from pytube import Playlist

YOUTUBE_STREAM_AUDIO = '140' # modify the value to download a different stream
DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'D:\\Users\\Jean-Pierre\\Downloads'

playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzwWSJNcZTMSW-v1x6MhHFKkwrGaEgQ-L')

# this fixes the empty playlist.videos list
playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")

print(len(playlist.video_urls))

for url in playlist.video_urls:
    print(url)

# physically downloading the audio track
for video in playlist.videos:
    audioStream = video.streams.get_by_itag(YOUTUBE_STREAM_AUDIO)
    audioStream.download(output_path=DOWNLOAD_DIR)
```

Comment: Trying this on a playlist with 1500+ videos and I can only manage to get 55 URLs out of it... any suggestions?

Comment: @PhysicsLover999 Do you have this exact repo installed? https://github.com/pytube/pytube

Comment: Not familiar with this library, how do I do the same but download video and not audio

Answer (score 7):

if one needs to download the highest quality video of each item in a playlist

```
playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZclsCzhzt4&list=PLk-w4cD8sJ6N6ffzp5A4PQaD76RvdpHLP')

for video in playlist.videos:
    print('downloading : {} with url : {}'.format(video.title, video.watch_url))
    video.streams.\
        filter(type='video', progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').\
        order_by('resolution').\
        desc().\
        first().\
        download(cur_dir)
```

Answer (score 6):

this code allows you to download a playlist to your assigned folder

```
import re
from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=Pd5k1hvD2apA0DwI3XMiSDqp')   
DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'D:\Video'
playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")    
print(len(playlist.video_urls))    
for url in playlist.video_urls:
    print(url)    
for video in playlist.videos:
    print('downloading : {} with url : {}'.format(video.title, video.watch_url))
    video.streams.\
        filter(type='video', progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').\
        order_by('resolution').\
        desc().\
        first().\
        download(DOWNLOAD_DIR)
```

Comment: Solving path issues on Windows :
import pathlib
...
DOWNLOAD_DIR = pathlib.Path("D:/DOWNLOAD/folder")

Answer (score 5):

```
from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGCkg2uj3PxUWhMDuTw3VKjM')
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
for video_url in playlist.video_urls:
    print(video_url)
playlist.download_all()
```

> ```
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjuHHI60s44
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z40N7b9NHTE
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvziRqkLrEU
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN2-87haa8k
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgI4UKyL0Lc
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvPIgm2SMG8
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpdmUmglPBA
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmVmJi5dR9c
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYNuKXjcriM
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWONqLqSxYc
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKmLXiA4zaQ
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DHCm9AlXvo
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cRaGaIZQlo
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkcEB96iMFk
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Fcf-8LPvws
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWLgdSgsBFo
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcKYFEgfV-I
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtSQIxDPnLc
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5kh_-6e4kk
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuWVDz-48-o
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yjc5Y7Wbmw
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5T59WsrNCU
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWldNGdX9zE
> ```

I'm using [pytube3](https://pypi.org/project/pytube3/) 9.6.4, **not pytube**.

Now `Playlist.video_urls` works well.

And `Playlist.populate_video_urls()` function was deprecated.

Comment: The 2 preceding examples don't work for me. I get the message :

```Number of videos in playlist: 0
C:\Users\...\test.py:4: 
DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function download_all (This function will be removed in the future. Please iterate through .videos).
  playlist.download_all('out/')
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py:216: 
DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function _path_num_prefix_generator (This 
function will be removed in the future.).
  prefix_gen = self._path_num_prefix_generator(reverse_numbering)```

Comment: I add that I checked that the url of examples has really more than 0 videos (and I tried with some other playlist url, with no effects).
And I'm using pytube3 9.6.4

Comment: The answer to my problem was found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661930/pytube3-playlist-returns-empty-list

Answer (score 3):

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist


SAVE_PATH = "E:/YouTube" #to_do


#link of the video to be downloaded
links= "https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLblh5JKOoLUL3IJ4- yor0HzkqDQ3JmJkc"

playlist = Playlist(links)

PlayListLinks = playlist.video_urls
N = len(PlayListLinks)
#print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(PlayListLinks))

print(f"This link found to be a Playlist Link with number of videos equal to {N} ")
print(f"\n Lets Download all {N} videos")

for i,link in enumerate(PlayListLinks):

    yt = YouTube(link)
    d_video = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    d_video.download(SAVE_PATH)
    print(i+1, ' Video is Downloaded.')
```

[image: Output]

You can check this repository to download playlists and individual videos and keep them in different directories.

https://github.com/pushpendra050/Pytube-for-Playlist-download

Answer (score 1):

```
import pytube
from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist('plylist link')
num = 0
for v in playlist.videos:
    print(v.watch_url)
    one = pytube.YouTube(v.watch_url)
    one_v = one.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    name = f"{0}" + one_v.default_filename
    one_v.download()
    num = num + 1
```

### Download all playlist

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: @MuhammadMohsinKhan Disagree. This code was the only code on this page that worked for me. Considering the context of what the OP is asking for i think this is fine. Anybody viewing this page will understand that what he's posted here is python code that uses the pytube library to download a youtube playlist... What else would you expect to be there? You also have the power to edit this answer if you think there's anything that could be added to it.

Answer (score 1):

This works flawlessly to download complete playlist

check pytube github to install

```
pip install pytube
```

Now, go to this folder and open cipher.py

```
D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pytube\
```

replace at line 273

```
function_patterns = [
        r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&\s*.*\|\|\s*(.*)\(',
        r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]{3})(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)',
    ]
```

main.py

```
from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwdnzlV3ogoXUifhvYB65lLJCZ74o_fAk')

playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")

print(len(playlist.video_urls))

for url in playlist.video_urls:
    print(url)

for video in playlist.videos:
    video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
```

Comment: What is the piont of the `playlist._video_regex` line?

Answer (score 1):

this work for me in windows 11 or 10.5
Original code: Jean-Pierre Schnyder

```
import re
from pytube import Playlist

DOWNLOAD_DIR = input ("Download dir")

playlist = input ("Link:")


playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")

print(len(playlist.video_urls))

for url in playlist.video_urls:
    print(url)

for video in playlist.videos:
    audioStream = video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    audioStream.download(output_path=DOWNLOAD_DIR)
```

Comment: playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_video_regex'

Answer (score 0):

Though it seems like a solved problem, but here is one of my solutions which may help you to download the playlist specifically as video of `1080P 30 FPS` or `720P 30 FPS` *(if 1080P not available)*.

```
from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLeo1K3hjS3uvCeTYTeyfe0-rN5r8zn9rw')
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))

# Loop through all videos in the playlist and download them
for video in playlist.videos:
    try:
        print(video.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4'))
        stream = video.streams.get_by_itag(137) # 137 = 1080P30
        stream.download()
    except AttributeError:
        stream = video.streams.get_by_itag(22) # 22, 136 = 720P30; if 22 still don't work, try 136
        stream.download()
    except:
        print("Something went wrong.")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Just takes the URLs in the playlist and downloads them one by one:

```py
from pytube import Playlist

download_url = input('URL of the video:')

playlist = Playlist(download_url)
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
for video_url in playlist.video_urls:
    print(video_url)
    urls.append(video_url)
    for url in urls:
        my_video = YouTube(url)

        print("*****************DOWNLOAD VID*************")
        print(my_video.title)

        my_video = my_video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        path = "PATH"
        my_video.download(path)
        print('******************************************') 
        print("VIDEO DOWNLOAD DONE\n\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

this may not work, the code below works for every case

```
from pytube import Playlist
from pytube import YouTube

from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPFKAG9rYOE&list=PLknwEmKsW8OtK_n48UOuYGxJPbSFrICxm')
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
for video_url in playlist.video_urls:
    print(video_url)
    video=YouTube(video_url)
    try:
       #video.streams.first().download()
       video.streams.filter(res="720p").first().download()
    except:
         continue
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First of all update the `pytube` module using following code

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

Here is my code which keeps track of the videos downloaded in case connection break.

```
from pytube import Playlist
import os
import re

def download(playlist):
    progress = None
    PATH = f'./{title}'
    with open(PATH+'/dependList.txt','r') as f:
        progress = int(f.read())

    videos = playlist.videos
    for i,video in enumerate(videos):
        if i >= progress:
            v = video.streams.filter(progressive=True,file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
            v.download(PATH+'/')
            with open(PATH+'/dependList.txt','w') as f:
                f.write(f'{i+1}')
        print(f'Downloaded {i+1} video')

link = input('Enter link:')
pl = Playlist(link)
total_videos = len(pl.videos)
print(f'Total Videos:{total_videos}')
title = ' '.join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", pl.title))
print(title)

if os.path.exists(title):
    length_file = len(os.listdir(title)) - 1
    if length_file!=total_videos:
        download(pl)
        print("DONE")
    else:
        print('Already Exist')
else:
    os.makedirs(f'./{title}')
    with open(f'./{title}/dependList.txt','w') as f:
        f.write('0')
    download(pl)
    print('DONE')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pytube import Playlist

# Replace with the URL of the YouTube playlist you want to download
playlist_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9cRVgocl8YYk_zFXqjaRUei7AUt4hDkp'

def download_playlist(url):
    playlist = Playlist(url)

    for video in playlist.videos:
        video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    download_playlist(playlist_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from pytube import Playlist

YOUTUBE_STREAM_AUDIO = '140' # modify the value to download a different stream
#DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'C:\\Users\\lima0\\Music\\DowloadMusicas\\MusicasLuciene'
DOWNLOAD_DIR = input("Caminho de Dowload seperado por 'duas barras invertidas': ") #\\

#playlist = Playlist('https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiOOw5gv01WIsEwTLKIDZBx-Fk4gGT35i&si=lBuYbwQ1KTWR2daf')
playlist = Playlist(input("Link da Playlist: "))

# this fixes the empty playlist.videos list
playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")

print("Número de Videos: ",len(playlist.video_urls))
n = len(playlist.video_urls)

for url in playlist.video_urls:
    print(url)


# physically downloading the audio track
for i, video in enumerate(playlist.videos, start=1):

    #print('Baixando: {} url : {}'.format(video.title, video.watch_url))
    print('Baixando {}/{}: {} url : {}'.format(i, n, video.title, video.watch_url))
    audioStream = video.streams.get_by_itag(YOUTUBE_STREAM_AUDIO)
    audioStream.download(output_path=DOWNLOAD_DIR)

print("Dowload Completo!")
```