# How do I stop pytube attempting to save a url as a file only when looping over videos to download from a playlist

Tags: python, moviepy, pytube

I have attempted to debug it using pdb from the error message, I can see that the problem closest to my problem occurs in audiowriter. This is especially interesting:

File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\io\ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 121, in close self.proc.stdin.close()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument https://youtube.com/watch?v=pc0mxOXbWIU

It seems to me that it's telling me it can't save the url as a file but it didn't attempt to do that until the 59th itteration

HOWEVER the function that looks like this

```
    def Youtube_playlist_downloader():
        import pytube
        playlist = pytube.Playlist(input("input playlist url here (note if it is a irl with &index=number at the end that's a song url not a playlist url):"))#note playlist is a list of urls
        num = 0
        for v in playlist.videos:
            print(v.watch_url)
            Video = pytube.YouTube(v.watch_url)
            Video_v = Video.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
            Name = Video_v.default_filename
            try:
                Video_v.download("./videos")
            except:
                print("Failed to download" + Name[:-3])
            num += 1
            try:
                audio = mp.VideoFileClip(r"./videos/" + Name)
                audio.audio.write_audiofile(r"./audio/" + Name[:-3] + Audio_type)
            except:
                print("Failed to extract audio from" + Name[:-3])
        Choice_choosing()
```

DOESN'T tell it to save as a url so i'm not certain why this is happening, there's no reason why i can't do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713364/14175385)
then loop over every file in the folder but I want to understand why this happens and have the options to play songs while waiting for the rest to download (not that i've attempted this)

[Here](https://pastebin.com/haLk8HQ9) is the full code if it helps thank you for any help in advance

Comment: You might like to rephrase the question and state the multiple objectives you like to achieve.