# How to remove 'cipher' error from YouTube video downloader and download video in mp3 format?

Tags: python, encryption, mp3, pytube

I am trying to create a **YouTube video downloader** in python using pytube and tkinter. Most of the videos are getting downloaded fine but in some videos I am getting the error as **'cipher'**. Can anyone help while this is happening?

Also I am trying to download in mp3 format but setting the 'audioonly' attribute to True downloads my file in mp4 format without the video. But I want the format in mp3. How can I do so?

Here is my code

```
def startDownload(url):
    global file_size
    path_to_save = askdirectory()
    if path_to_save is None:
        return

    try:
            global MaxFileSize, fileSizeInBytes
            choice = youtubeChoicesLabel.get()
            url=urlField.get()
            yt = YouTube(url)
            nome = yt.title
            # video2 = urlField.get()

            if (choice == download_choices[1]):
                print("720p video is downloading")
                selectVideo = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').first()

            elif (choice == download_choices[2]):
                print("Audio file is downloading")
                
                # selectVideo =yt.streams.get_audio_only()
                # new_filename= nome + '*.mp3'
                # default_filename=  nome + '*.mp4'
                # ffmpeg = ('ffmpeg -i ' %path_to_save %default_filename + new_filename)
                # subprocess.run(ffmpeg, shell=True)
                selectVideo = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
                
                
            elif (choice == download_choices[0]):
                return

            
                fileSizeInBytes = selectVideo.filesize
                MaxFileSize = fileSizeInBytes/1024000
                MB =str(MaxFileSize)+ "MB"
                print("File Size = : {:00.000f}".format (MaxFileSize))

            
            

            
            # yt = YouTube(url)
            # st=yt.streams.first()
            st= selectVideo
            yt.register_on_complete_callback(complete_download)
            yt.register_on_progress_callback(progress_download)
            file_size=st.filesize
            st.download(output_path=path_to_save)
        




    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is pretty simple, it's there in the GitHub repo, but since this question came up here, this is how I fixed it. It's not due to the way your file works, it's a problem that happened because YouTube changed their search patterns or something from cipher to signatureCipher.

- First, say `pip install pytube3` in the terminal.
- Second, go to the path - `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pytube`. Keep in mind the path will vary so replace `<user>` with your Windows username and `python37-32` with your Python version that you install pytube on.
- Third, open `extract.py` from the above navigated directory and head onto line 301 or search for the line:

```
cipher_url = [
    parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
]
```

- Now replace it with:

```
cipher_url = [
     parse_qs(formats[i]["signatureCipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
]
```

In case you damage this file while making changes to it, just say `pip uninstall pytube3` and then install it again, and repeat. Keep in mind your imports will still be `import pytube`.

Comment: Please give me the solution for downloading the YouTube files in mp3 format.

Comment: @SOHAMDASBISWAS. Maybe as a new Q, or just read the docs, its pretty simple i think, i dont use this much. But take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420304/download-video-in-mp3-format-using-pytube)