# Difficulty opening an exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable

I have written a youtube converter which is working fine when i am running it from pycharm. I tried several ways to use pyinstaller to create an exe file out of the .py file below.

From the cd, in the correct directory,

when i try `pyinstaller --onefile -w filename.py` or `pyinstaller --onefile filename.py`, when i try to open the executable file, I get fatal error could not run script.

when i try `pyinstaller filename.py` or `python -m PyInstaller filename.py`, and then try to open the executable file, the cmd flashes and then nothing.

From pycharm, when I run the program, tkinter opens and all the functionalities are good.

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from pytube import YouTube
import youtube_dl

window = Tk()
window.title("Convertiseur Youtube 1.0")
window.configure(background="silver")
window.geometry("600x250")

def clickvideo():
   url = textentry.get()
   YouTube(url).streams.filter(file_extension='mp4').first().download()
   textentry.delete(0, END)
   status.set("Succès! Le fichier mp4 a été envoyé à l'endroit à partir du quel ce programme est exécuté.")


def clickaudio():
   video_info = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(
      url=textentry.get(), download=False
   )
   filename = f"{video_info['title']}.mp3"
   options = {
      'format': 'bestaudio/best',
      'keepvideo': False,
      'outtmpl': filename,
      'postprocessors': [{
         'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
         'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
         'preferredquality': '192',
      }]
   }
   with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
      ydl.download([video_info['webpage_url']])
   textentry.delete(0, END)
   status.set("Succès! Le fichier mp3 a été envoyé à l'endroit à partir du quel ce programme est exécuté.")


Label(window, background="silver").pack()

Label(window, text="Lien Youtube à convertir:", background="silver").pack()

Label(window, background="silver").pack()

textentry = Entry(window, width=60)
textentry.get()
textentry.pack()

Label(window, background="silver").pack()

videobutton = Button(window, text="Convertir en vidéo", width=16, command=clickvideo).pack()

Label(window, background="silver").pack()

audiobutton = Button(window, text="Convertir en audio", width=16, command=clickaudio).pack()

Label(window, background="silver").pack()

status = StringVar()
status.set("Si rien ne se passe, il y a un problème avec le lien (typo ou mauvais lien).")

status_label = Label(window, background="silver", textvariable=status)
status_label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, there will be a error popping up at the console that flashes, try to take a capture of it and include the error code here

Comment: There really seems to be no error, it just flashes, then disappears, no additional messages.

Comment: Start the exe from a command prompt then see what it shows

Comment: Thank you barry!

C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\youtubeconverter\dist\guizmoytc>guizmoytc.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guizmoytc.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'
[6576] Failed to execute script guizmoytc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that pytube was installed in your virtual env given by pycharm and not in global python version, so say this in the terminal:

```
pip install pytube
```

*Actually pytube3

Then run the pyinstaller line of code in the terminal where you installed the library from, and it should fix the error.

Comment: Yes indeed i had installed those modules on the pycharm venv and not on my computer (not on python?)Alright, I installed pytube and youtube-dl in same same location as my python is located. install was successful. I reran the pyinstaller from my pycharm files. I got the exe file. I tried opening it from the command, now i get this: 

C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\youtubeconverter\dist>guizmoytc.exe

C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\youtubeconverter\dist>

And 5 seconds later, ''fatal error failed to execute script guizmoytc''

Comment: Am i installing the modules at the right place? Do i have to install where my python is located or wherepycharm is located?

Comment: Ok pardon actually i was using a different method, this is the error i get now when i used the same method as earlier:

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guizmoytc.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pytube\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)```

Comment: ```File "pytube\streams.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pytube\extract.py", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'quote' from 'pytube.compat' (C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\youtubeconverter\dist\guizmoytc\pytube\compat.pyc)
[9596] Failed to execute script guizmoytc```

Comment: @guizmo Yes, to fix this say `pip install pytube3` and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64091230/13382000)

Comment: @Cool_Cloud Working, thank you good sir. I have learned alot today

Comment: @Cool_Cloud how do i even do that? I cannot upvote i am too new

Comment: @guizmo - Please take a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)